# Many to Many relation with custom table in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models with many to many relationships with custom table such as Clinic and Doctor and custom table DoctorClinic.
how could I get the list of Doctors based on Clinics?
this is my views.py

```
class ClinicDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Clinic
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['doctor_list'] = self.doctor_set.annotate(
        shift=F('doctor_list__shift'),
        timming=F('doctor_list__timming')
        return context
```

I got the error **object has no attribute doctor_set**
here is my models.py

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 18)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices = CHTYPE)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clinic_hospital = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic, through='DoctorHospital')

class DoctorHospital(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(ClinicHospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # time_from = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,blank=True)
    # time_to = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=False,blank=True)
    timing = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
```

and here is my urls.py

```
path('clinichospital/<int:pk>/',views.ClinicHospitalDetailView.as_view(),name = 'clinichospital_detail')
```

please help me how can doctor list I show.

Comment: `self` is your view, not a `Clinic`.

Comment: but it is not working with Clinic too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class ClinicDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Clinic
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    client_id = self.kwargs['pk'] # Pull id out of url
    client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
    context['doctor_list'] = client.doctor_set.annotate(
        shift=F('doctor_list__shift'),
        timming=F('doctor_list__timming') 
    ) # Missing bracket
    return context
```

Comment: it worked client.doctor_set.all() instead of client.doctor_set.annotate.

Comment: but I custom table field too like shift and timing from custom table

Comment: If you feel the answer is the best. You can click the tick under the upvote icon to accept it

Comment: I updated the answer, seems you were missing a bracket